# What is required for Monterey's Adaptive Sync support?

Tags: thunderbolt, displayport, monterey

I was excited to try Monterey's adaptive sync, but it doesn't seem to be working with my hardware.

### My Hardware

I have an LG 27UD68 display, with a (somewhat limited) Freesync range of 40-60hz. This is an older model that AMD [categorizes](https://www.amd.com/en/products/freesync-monitors) as "Freesync" (not *Freesync Premium* or *Freesync Premium Pro*), and it's not on NVidia's "G-SYNC Compatible" [list](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/g-sync-monitors/specs/).

My Windows PC (with an AMD GPU) is able to connect with Freesync.

I've connected my Mac (2018 MBP, Radeon 560X) to the display two different ways:

1. Thunderbolt port -> thunderbolt cable -> thunderbolt dock -> full-size displayport cable -> display

   The dock is a [Caldigit TS3+](https://www.caldigit.com/ts3-plus/). I'm not sure whether to expect adaptive sync to make it through the thunderbolt chain.
2. Thunderbolt port -> adapter cable -> display

   The cable is a [Uni USB-C to DisplayPort Cable](https://uniaccessories.com/collections/cables/products/usb-c-to-displayport-cable-4k-60hz). [Amazon reviews](https://www.amazon.com/DisplayPort-uni-Thunderbolt-Compatible-More-Gray/product-reviews/B075V27G2R/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewopt_kywd?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=1&filterByKeyword=freesync) suggest that it ought to work with freesync.

System Information summarizes the display thus:

```
LG Ultra HD:
  Resolution:   5120 x 2880 (5K/UHD+ - Ultra High Definition Plus)
  UI Looks like:    2560 x 1440 @ 60.00Hz
  Framebuffer Depth:    30-Bit Color (ARGB2101010)
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Rotation: Supported
  Automatically Adjust Brightness:  Yes
  Connection Type:  Thunderbolt/DisplayPort
```

What I'm seeing is, the available refresh rates include only 30 and 60, no "Variable" option:

[image: 30-60]

For contrast, when the feature is working, it should look something like this:

[image: Variable refresh]
(image from [Ars' Monterey review](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/10/macos-12-monterey-the-ars-technica-review/10/#h1))

### The Question

So I'm left wondering: *under what circumstances is adaptive sync expected to work?* Apple's "Use Adaptive Sync with your Mac" [support page](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-adaptive-sync-with-your-mac-mchld453162e/mac) offers no guidance.

Perhaps there's a specific list of supported displays? Or maybe it requires a range larger than my display's 40-60hz?

Can anyone chime in with hardware combinations that they've seen work?

Comment: Same here. Trying with a G-Sync compatible ASUS monitor on my Mac mini M1, no luck. Bought a Display Port 1.4 cable to Thunderbolt 3, I have all display options available, but no Adaptive Sync. Disappointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a support page that lists specific hardware!:

> - Any Mac with Apple silicon
> - Any of these Intel-based Mac models:
>
>   - MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports)
>   - MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)
>   - MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2020)
>   - iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2020)
>   - Mac Pro (2019) when used with any of these Radeon Pro MPX modules: W5500X, W5700X, W6800X, W6900X, or W6800X Duo

( https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212232 )

So the 2018 machine in the question above is not supported.

Also I can now report that an M1 Pro offers 40-60hz for the LG 27UD68.